# Кластерный анализ (k-means) на python

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, cluster

На данный момент реализую кластерный анализ методом `k-means`, и реализовать его необходимо именно силами Python. В Python я абсолютно несведущий, знаком с C и ему подобными языки, не много с Java и поэтому Python выглядит для меня совершенно не понятно.

Умение собирать информацию с просторов интернета никто не отменял, поэтому я нашел блог, где человек демонстрирует реализацию `k-means` и приводит код. Естественно, я попытался позаимствовать его, поправляя недочеты и разбираясь как оно работает. Вот ссылка (там весь код, если интересно): [k means](http://blog.esemi.ru/2012/08/k-means-python.html), а функция сбора данных из файла показана [здесь](http://blog.esemi.ru/2012/02/python.html).
С первого же запуска `get_data` начались проблемы, то `file("имя файла")` устарело и надо `open()`, то в `numpy.array` нельзя `map` передать. В общем, построчное исправление ошибок выдаваемых интерпретатором уперлось в тупик и я решил обратиться к вам за помощью. Не могли бы вы своим наметанным профессиональным взглядом посмотреть код и указать где в нем ошибки/недочеты? Запускаю я его на Python 3.x. Верно ли это?
Код:

```
import numpy as np
def get_data():
"""Возвращает списки идентификаторов объектов и матрицу значений"""
source = [row.strip().split(';') for row in open("export.csv")]
names = [row[0] for row in source[1:]]
data = [map(float, row[1:]) for row in source[1:]]

return names, norm(data)
def norm(data):
"""Нормирование данных"""

matrix = np.array(list([data, 'f']))
len_val = len(matrix[1, :])

for i in range(len_val):
    local_min = matrix[:, i].min()

    if local_min != 0.0:
        matrix[:, i] -= local_min

    local_max = matrix[:, i].max()
    if local_max != 0.0:
        matrix[:, i] /= local_max

return matrix.tolist()

if __name__ == '__main__':
get_data()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулями - Pandas (для чтения/записи/обработки данных) и `SciKit Learn` (для использования алгоритмов машинного обучения).

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

# read data (drop last empty column, caused by an extra (last) colon in the header)
data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';').dropna(axis=1, how='all')

# normalize data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(data.drop('Пользователь', 1))

# clustering
n_clusters = 3
km = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)

# fit & predict clusters
data['cluster'] = km.fit_predict(X)

# results - we should have 3 clusters: [0,1,2] 
print(data)

# cluster's centroids
print(km.cluster_centers_)
```

Результат:

```
In [47]: data
Out[47]:
     Пользователь  Вопрос№1  Вопрос№2  Вопрос№3  Вопрос№4  Вопрос№5  Вопрос№6  Вопрос№7  Вопрос№8  Вопрос№9  Вопрос№10  Вопрос№11  \
0    91.76.155.87         2         2         1         5         3         4         1         1         2          2          1
1  188.123.252.12         2         1         1         6         6         1         2         1         2          3          4
2    46.242.13.93         3         3         1         4         1         2         5         3         1          5          1
3   94.19.223.144         2         2         1         5         6         4         1         1         1          2          4
4     46.39.46.15         2         2         2         5         4         3         3         4         3          2          4

   Вопрос№12  Вопрос№13  Вопрос№14  Вопрос№15  Вопрос№16  Вопрос№17  Вопрос№18  cluster
0          3          5          4          5          6          6          4        2
1          5          3          3          4          5          5          5        0
2          5          4          5          5          5          6          4        1
3          5          2          4          6          6          6          5        2
4          4          4          3          3          4          5          3        0
```

---

```
In [48]: print(km.cluster_centers_)
[[0.         0.25       0.5        0.75       0.8        0.33333333 0.375      0.5        0.75       0.16666667 1.         0.75       0.5        0.
       0.16666667 0.25       0.
  0.5       ]
 [1.         1.         0.         0.         0.         0.33333333 1.         0.66666667 0.         1.         0.         1.         0.66666667 1.
       0.66666667 0.5        1.
  0.5       ]
 [0.         0.5        0.         0.5        0.7        1.         0.         0.         0.25       0.         0.5        0.5        0.5        0.5
       0.83333333 1.         1.
  0.75      ]]
```

---

чтобы предсказать кластеры для новых строк - надо сначала нормализовать данные используя тот же `scaler`:

```
X_new = scaler.transform(new_data.drop('Пользователь', 1))
```

и собственно предсказание кластера:

```
new_data['cluster'] = km.predict(X_new)
```

Comment: Может у меня csv файл приведен к не совсем верному виду? Я его сделал так:
_Пользователь;Вопрос№1;...Вопрос№18\n*IP-adress-user*;2;2;1;5;3;4;1;1;2;2;1;3;5;4;5;6;6;4_
Шапка, и потом строчка за строчкой ip, и через ; ответы на вопросы. Data вроде собралась нормально [картинка](https://ibb.co/k7xjic), но вот дальше он ругается на ip адреса , мол нельзя конвертировать строку в float. Как это исправить? Просто мне нужно, чтобы ответы людей можно было идентифицировать и по итогу указать человек к какому кластеру он принадлежит

Comment: @AndrewFitcher, приведите в вопросе небольшой но воспроизводимый пример данных. Советую ознакомиться: ["Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: Постараюсь сформулировать четко и по смыслу. На данный момент имею [это](https://ibb.co/hx4beH). Как я понял все сработало верно. 3 кластера и их центроиды. А вот обрабатываемые данные: ([изначальные](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q5DWgzt9aNS60CiHY2SpT2iWS8025ylZ6ilrzHQUH9Q/edit?usp=sharing) и [без ip](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15UJYMVZAl9qYY3bMZ4sqEG98RCW5-NoVJOypsl3FuVU/edit?usp=sharing). Основной вопрос: "Как определить принадлежность того или иного пользователя к тому или иному кластеру, имея вышеописанные центроиды и кластеры?"